# Mercurial update source code with current revision numer

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I there a way to update a source code file with the current revision number each time i do a commit? 
Something like, let's say that in my footer.php i have something like

```
Rev. number: {REVISION}
```

And when i commit {REVISION} will be replaced with current revision number.
I'm using TortoiseHG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RCS-type keyword expansion:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KeywordPlan

But if your last changeset didn't include `footer.php`, then the keywords won't be expanded, so your probably better off having some build procedure write the current revision ID via `hg id`. There's an example on how to do this in the link above.

Comment: The keyword plan page to which you linked has a big paragraph explaining why keywords are a terrible idea for a DVCS.  Your follow-on idea (should be a second answer) of using the build script to inject the version string is much better.  A great one is `hg log --template '{latesttag}-{latesttagdistance}-${node|short}`